# How to write a Declaration File for a Library that exports an already typed Library

Tags: typescript

I want to write an `index.d.ts` for a library, that puts a thin abstraction layer over *some* exports of an already typed library. The rest is a 1:1 export from the original library. How would I write the `index.d.ts` declaration file ?

#### Situation: Exporting of already typed library

The library imports everything from React-Router-Dom ([which is very well typed](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/react-router-dom)) in its `index.js`, sugars a few exports, than exports everything in its own `index.js`.

```js
    import * as ReactRouterDom from 'react-router-dom'

    // (...modification on some ReactRouterDom props)

    module.exports = {
      ...ReactRouterDom,
    }
```

#### Question: Declaration File

I'd PR the `index.d.ts` (with eventual type dependencies) to this new library which would be gladly merged. So it does not have to live on Definitely Typed.

Due to a lack of experience, I am not sure if I need to copy all the definitions for ReactRouterDom or rather, how such a problem is approach in general.

Thanks alot

Dino

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can re-export the declarations:

```
// your-lib/index.d.ts
export * from 'react-router-dom'
export const Prompt = 42
```

Would be a declaration file which is identical to react-router-dom except `Prompt` is now a number instead of what it was before.